# How to handle drop down list

Tags: php

I am trying to make this code work for using a drop-down list. Is it possible that `strip_tags` does not work for drop down list? If any one can help me it will be very helpful

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationSelect.js" type="text/javascript">       </script>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationSelect.css" rel="stylesheet"     type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<span id="spryselect1">
<label>
<form method="post" action="b.php">
<select name="s" id="s">
 <option value="friends" selected>Friends</option>
                            <option value="search">Search engine</option>
                            <option value="ad">Advertisement</option>
                            <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<div class="col span-2-of-3">
                        <input type="submit" value="Send it!">
                    </div>
                    </form>
</label>
<span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var spryselect1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationSelect("spryselect1");
//-->
   </script>
   </body>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php


include_once('connection.php');
$s=strip_tags($_POST['s']);

if (@$_POST['submit'])
{
$queryreg = mysql_query("

                    INSERT INTO p VALUES ('$s')

                    "); 


}

else 

echo "Not done";

?>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem, and what is the relevance of strip_tags.... besides protecting yourself if anybody has generated a request manually, the value of `s` will be a string containing one of the values `friends`, `search`, `ad` or `other` (the values of the select options)

Comment: Note that you are susceptible to SQL injection, and are using an out-dated and deprecated database interface

Comment: And why is your form wrapped in a label tag?

Comment: Then what should I use instead of label ? I have used dream weaver auto drop down list and it was generated automatically. I am working in amateur level so please help , Mark

Comment: Well start by explaining what your problem actually is? Why do you believe strip_tags() doesn't work with drop down lists? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Then please tell me how to implement , Mark

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing? What is your issue? what problem are you having?

Comment: I just want to insert values in my database using drop down list

Comment: So what actually happens when you try? Do you get any errors? Does the wrong value get inserted in your database? Does nothing get inserted into the database? Does the form not submit?

Comment: While strip_tags() isn't serving any useful purpose here, it won't be responsible for whatever is happening

Comment: I have done  it. Thank you sir for your kind response , mark